# Undefined reference to function in case of a library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc

I am in the middle of porting code from Visual Studio to Mingw GCC. This component works fine in Visual studio however Mingw GCC complains about a undefined reference to a function. I have isolated the situation and am putting down the code here

File : Rng.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef RNG_EXPORTS
#define RNG_API  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RNG_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

RNG_API unsigned long GetRandom(unsigned long range);
```

File : Rng.cpp

```
#include "Rng.h"
#include "RngKiss.h"

static  TRngFile                    gRngFile;

unsigned long GetRandom(unsigned long range)
{
    gRngFile.generate_rnd();  //Linker Error : Undefined Reference to function.

    ....
}
```

File: RngKiss.h

```
#ifndef __RNGKISS_H__
#define __RNGKISS_H__

#ifndef ULONG
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
#endif  //ULONG


typedef struct
{
    ULONG   w, x, y, z;
} TRngRecord;


typedef struct
{
    TRngRecord  current, seed;
    ULONG   generate_rnd(void);
} TRngFile;

#endif
```

File : RngKiss.cpp

```
#include "RngKiss.h"


ULONG   TRngFile::generate_rnd(void)
{
    ULONG d;
    return  d;
}
```

This is my output.

```
g++.exe -L..\..\..\mingw64\lib\boost -o bin\Debug\TestCodeBlocks.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\Rng.o obj\Debug\RngKiss.o   
obj\Debug\Rng.o: In function `GetRandom(unsigned long)':
C:/Users/admin/TestCodeBlocks/Rng.cpp:8: undefined reference to `TRngFile::generate_rnd()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions on why I am getting this linker error and how i can resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fallen foul of a bug (or at least an eccentricity) in your `mingw64` compiler, in the rather obscure matter of
compiling unnamed structs. I don't know what version you have, but my `mingw32` 4.8.1
has the same behaviour:

These `typedef`s in `rngKiss.h`:-

```
typedef struct
{
    ULONG   w, x, y, z;
} TRngRecord;


typedef struct
{
    TRngRecord  current, seed;
    ULONG   generate_rnd(void);
} TRngFile;
```

You may think that they respectively define a `struct` type called `TRngRecord` and another called
`TRngFile`, but strictly they define `TRngRecord` and `TRngFile` to be aliases of `struct` types
which themselves are unnamed.

The difference should be merely conceptual. So it is for
Microsoft's compiler and for [TDM GCC 4.9.2](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) on Windows, and so it is for
GCC 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.1 on Linux.

Our `mingw` compilers, however, appear to hold that members of the *unamed* `struct` typedefed as
`TRngFile` must have static linkage. Mine generates:

```
Dump of file rngKiss.o

File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file
    rngKiss.cpp
002 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    Static       | __ZN8TRngFile12generate_rndEv
...
```

Hence the linkage error. Whereas TDM GCC 4.9.2 generates:

```
Dump of file rngKiss.o

File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file
    rngKiss.cpp
002 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    External     | _ZN8TRngFile12generate_rndEv
...
```

There are 3 solutions for this:

Change your compiler, say to TDM GCC.

Give names to your typedefed `struct`s:

```
typedef struct TRngRecord
{
    ULONG   w, x, y, z;
} TRngRecord;


typedef struct TRngFile
{
    TRngRecord  current, seed;
    ULONG   generate_rnd(void);
} TRngFile;
```

or best of all:

Drop the `typedef`s, which are a strange and unnecessary way of naming classes in C++:

```
struct TRngRecord
{
    ULONG   w, x, y, z;
};

struct  TRngFile
{
    TRngRecord  current, seed;
    ULONG   generate_rnd(void);
}; 

....

#include "rngKiss.h"
...
static  TRngFile                    gRngFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a few ideas come to mind.

1) the '::' scope operator is most often used to access a method of a class.  
   (another common use is to reference a function in a namespace)
   However, I do not see any class definition header file.
   (normally, the class header file is the same name as the class)

2) there has to be a prototype in a class header file 
   (usually this is part of the class declaration/interface) 
   for the generate_rnd() method.
```

So, where is the class header?

So, where is the method prototype?

Answer (score 0):

the question states that the function is in a library.

this indicates the linker statement is missing either the '-Lpath to the library directory' and/or '-ltruncated libary name'

Comment: Both the cpp and header file are in the same library